# Redirecting only graphics of a X client to another X server?

Tags: x11, xserver

Support I have two computers. Each computer has a X server running. And one of the computers also have some GUI applications running on it.

Now I want to keep the GUI applications still running on the same computer, and they're still getting keyboard and mouse input from the same computer, while redirect their display content to the X server on the other computer. The role of the displaying X server is simply rendering, so device sharing solutions like Synergy is not satisfied in this case. It may sound strange, but is essential for security issues.

I'd like to know whether it is possible to make X server work like this. If there is no existing solution, will it takes much effort to modify X server source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want either Synergy: http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/ or x11vnc: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/

Answer (score 2):

I've just discovered Window Shifter (http://shifter.devloop.org.uk).

With it, you can create a "read only copy" of your display and show it on another computer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use VNC to achieve this.